# Query to get top 10 users from MongoDb in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

So basically I have a collection that looks like this(other fields omitted):

```
[{
 user: mail1@test.com
},

{
 user: mail1@test.com
},
{
 user: mail1@test.com
},
{
 user: mail2@test.com
},
{
 user: mail2@test.com
},
{
 user: mail3@test.com
}
```

]

I'm looking for a way to query MongoDB in order to get the top 10 active users(those with the most records in DB). Is there an easy way to get this, perhaps just using the interface?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a simple group aggregation will give you the needed result?

```java
db.Users.aggregate(
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { count: -1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    },
    {
        $project: {
            user: "$_id",
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `$sortByCount` for aggregation.

```
List<UserCount> getTop10UserCount() {
  return mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    newAggregation(
      User.class,
      sortByCount("user"),
      limit(10),
      project("_id", "count")
    ), 
    UserCount.class
  );
}

static class UserCount {
  String _id;
  Integer count;
  // constructors, getters or setters..
}
```